# Print failing to render stylesheet

Tags: javascript, php, printing, media-queries

I am trying to build up a print styling sheet and have a simple test framework which Ive been struggling with for hours. Ive read lots of stuff on SO and elsewhere about the use of media print but none of the configs work for me.

**The problem**

The print window opens-no problem and the print.css stylesheet is being read correctly on the opened print window (red headline). But when the print is actually rendered (ie the physical print) I get no headline styling. Also tried media="print" and removing the media attribute - all with no luck.

```
    //js 
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                $('#print_btn').click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var w = window.open();
                    var printOne = $('.contentToPrint').html();
                    var printTwo = $('.print_div').html();
                    w.document.write('<html>');
                    w.document.write('<head>');
                    w.document.write('<title>Calculation</title>');
                    w.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/Stylesheets/print.css" media="all">');
                    w.document.write('</head>');
                    w.document.write('<body>');
                    w.document.write('<h1 class="test">Copy - Calculation Estimate</h1><hr />' + printOne + '<hr />' + printTwo);
                    w.document.write('</body></html>');
                    w.window.print();
                    w.document.close();
                    return false;
                });
            });
    </script>
```

// test style sheet-print.css (tried with and without media wrapper)

```
            @media print
            {
                .test 
                    {
                    color: red;
                    }
                }
```

ps- Just one other thing. When I add a style inline to the H1 tag it prints the style correctly.

Comment: Although I can't find evidence supporting me but, I (by trial and error) found out that adding media queries from a css through javascript (or simply not being there during initial page load) will sometimes (if no most of the time) stop them from being applied. So my suggestion is to include them in the page you're calling from, or in your case prepare a simple html file and `w.document.write` into it or you can simply pass those 2 vars as $_GET vars, and echo them inside the print html file.

Comment: What is the behaviour if you add border: 10px solid black to the .test selector in your stylesheet?

Debugging with colors when dealing with print can result in many odd behaviours.

Comment: I tried this on my print.css stylesheet @media print {.test  {border: solid black 10px;} } and Im not getting any styling unless I remove the media print wrapper. If I remove it the media print the print window shows the correct styling but the physical print-still no luck

Comment: You open a new window and have an own print.css. You don't need `@media print`. That's only useful if you don't put print styling in a separate file.